# trying to make a custom front page using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i ma working with WordPress, I am trying to change the front page of a website, by making it into different sections:

(an image that covers the header, menu and a slider with 3 pictures that changes ever few seconds)
one section has the images of our partner companies,
in the next section I talked about our employees,
next section a quote about the company with costume background image
next section our services,
then contact information (just address)
finally a small footer.

I also want to know where I can find the middle section that the title is highlighted blue and there is just one line under it. Is this part a seprate page ?

How can I make my front page into different sections, this is what it lookalike[image]:

something like this [templates](https://oceanwebthemes.com/themes/metlux/). I am new to wordpress and I need a little help can someone help me out here?

Comment: You can create Home page template.then select that page template in one page set that page as frontpage in wordpress.You can also choose advanced custom fields for that home page.

Comment: @developerme where can I do that from ? do I have to go to new pages and create a new home page and then do it there?